# How to keep a temporary directory open while opening and closing another?

Tags: python, temporary-directory

I am trying to write a function that will go through multiple zip file full of png's to compile all pictures into a single zip. Each zip has it's contents labeled 0-# of png's so I need to rename all of the files in order then zip them together. I have everything completed with temporary directories, one for renaming  `rename_dir`  and one for zipping everything `collect_dir`. I am running into a problem where only the final zip will be saved, but the names inside will be correct. I think that the `collect_dir` is being closed in between each iteration and thus deleting everything in it, so when it zips in the end only the final group will be included. Is there a way to keep one directory open (`collect_dir`) while opening and closing another (`rename_dir`) (without ever closing `collect_dir`, at least until the function is finished and zipping is complete)

this is the portion of code i think is relevant

```
 with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as collect_dir:
            with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as rename_dir:

                # unpack files into temp directory
                shutil.unpack_archive(iter_dir_path, rename_dir)
                
                # bug checking
                # print(os.listdir(rename_dir))

                for pic in range(len(os.listdir(rename_dir))):
                    # Get path for pic
                    old_name = os.path.join(rename_dir, str(pic) + ".png")

                    # Create new path for pic in collect directory and changing name to pic count
                    new_name = os.path.join(collect_dir, str(pic_count) + ".png")

                    # bug checking
                    # names_old.append(old_name)
                    # names_new.append(new_name)

                    # Rename path (moves file)
                    os.rename(old_name, new_name)

                    pic_count += 1

                # Create final zip
                save_path = os.path.dirname(download_path)
                final_dir_path = os.path.join(save_path, name_and_volume)
                archive = shutil.make_archive(final_dir_path, 'zip', collect_dir)
```

Comment: What does that _"I am running into a problem where only the final zip will be saved, but the names inside will be correct."_ mean exactly?

Comment: Why do you do that `for pic in range(len(os.listdir(rename_dir)))` in combination with `str(pic) + ".png"`?

Comment: I think you should make the code more self-contained, and also add relevant features (there's no looping over input ZIP-files, for example, it's unclear how the output filename(s) are constructed, etc.). I suspect that you overwrite the created archives here `archive = shutil.make_archive(final_dir_path, 'zip', collect_dir)` over and over again. Maybe create it outside the loop and append the new renamed files.

Comment: @Timus I start with zip 1 and zip 2. Zip 1 contains png labeled 0-57, zip 2 contains png labeled 0-25.Currently i end up with a final zip containing all pngs from zip 2 labeled 58-83 (as they should be). You did make me realize that my archive command was inside the loop and getting rewritten, however when i moved it out of the loop (unindented twice) I am getting errored out saying "system cannot locate ```collect_dir``` " I'm thinking with statements are causing me to lose the ability to control when these directories open/close, do you know any resources to be able to do this manually? tyvm

Comment: @Timus figured it out, i had everything inside another for loop that was causing the rewriting :P Thanks for your help i think i needed someone with experience (you) to help a beginner (me) look at my program in a diff way

Answer (score 0):

archive command at the end, not inside a for loop

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).